# Can I animate with Adobe Edge Animate and import to Xcode using Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, animation, adobe-edge

I would like to animate using Adobe Edge (html5). I would then like to proceed to import my animation in Xcode for an iPad app (IOS 8). I will be using Objective-C for this project. Is there any way to do so?

If not what are my alternatives? Keep in mind I want to animate using some sort of GUI application.

Comment: Learning CoreAnimation would be the "alternative". There's no magic conversion between HTML5 and Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on what sort of animations you want to create and how they will be used in your app. One possible way is to integrate the SpriteKit library into your UI, which can be useful for making animations or interactive artwork in your UI.

If you go this route, you can create an animation as a movie clip symbol in Adobe Animate. (Adobe Edge Animate has been discontinued and effectively replaced by what is currently called Adobe Animate). Then right-click your symbol in Animate and select **Export PNG Sequence**. This will produce the frames of your animation as PNG images, which you can then animate in your app using SpriteKit. Animate can also export art assets as a sprite sheet or texture atlas.

You would need to get familiar with the SpriteKit library to go this route. As other users pointed out, there are alternate approaches you could take.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know this would work would be to use a webview in your ObjectiveC code. Then you would point your web view to the local HTML/JS files generated by Edge Animate. Basically this is how Cordova does things.

Answer (score 0):

You could user alternatives like Phonegap,  or create your own UIWebView and charge the www folder.